# WPF Horizontal Listbox fill vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm making a list of products that display within a listbox that scrolls horizontally. I have the list scrolling horizontally however I only ever get 1 row of items even though the list box is high enough to populate 2 rows before it starts scrolling horizontally.

Part of my WPF code.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="productTemplate">
     <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="10" Height="10">
          <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="288" Height="320"/>
          <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
          <Label Content="{Binding Cost}" />
     </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox Width="1334" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource productTemplate}" Height="865" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListBox.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
    </ListBox.Background>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I'm looking for: [image]

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WrapPanel that is used as ItemsPanel must have vertical orientation, and the ListBox must not scroll vertically:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Damn nab it I was so close to trying this ¬¬ Cheers (y)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code will help you. The following code will help you to bind images in the following manner.

[image]

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="detailList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="90">
                <Image Width="80" Source="{Binding Type,
                    Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="11" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```